# tabulator set column layout according screen resolution

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying latest [tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) and need help.
Can someone show the right way how to change tabulator layout from 'fitData' to 'fitColumns'
according screen width?
All I have done is screen width detection :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).resize(function() {
      var width = $( window ).width();
      if(width > 800) {
          console.log("size > 800");
          userTable.options.layout = "fitColumns";
          userTable.redraw(true);
      }
      if(width < 800) {
          console.log("size < 800");
          userTable.options.layout = "fitData";
          userTable.redraw(true);
      }
  }); });
```

But this code does not work!
Can someone help?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant alter the layout option once the table has loaded, you would have to destroy the table and reload it

The best option would be to do this when you first create the table:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    layout:window.innerWidth > 800 ? "fitColumns" : "fitData",
    columns:[],
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. Have a look at the responsive module options too. It reconfigures the table to fit better on mobile devices